# Implementing a Modal Form with Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm a junior developer and I have been having a hard time trying to implement a modal form in Flask. Both the Sign Up Modal and the Login Modal are on the same HTML page. It keeps saying form undefined. below is the code

The code in my form.py

```
class SignupForm(Form):
    username = StringField('', [validators.Length(min=4, max=30)])
    email = StringField('', [validators.length(min=6, max=50)])
    password = PasswordField('', [
        validators.DataRequired(),
        validators.EqualTo('confirm', message="Password do not match")])
    confirm = PasswordField('', [validators.length(min=6, max=50), validators.DataRequired()])
    create = SubmitField('Sign up')

class LoginForm(Form):
    email = StringField(" ", [validators.Length(min=6, max=50), validators.DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('', [validators.DataRequired(),validators.Length(min=2, max=50)])
    submit = SubmitField('login')
    remember = BooleanField('remember me')`

def signup():
    # mysql = MySQL(c_app)
    form  = SignupForm(request.form)

     return render_template('signup.html',form=form)

@loginv.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm(request.form)

    return render_template("signin.html", form=form)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    return original_handler(e)
  File "C:\Users\Mr Ayo\.virtualenvs\cta\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1737, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Mr Ayo\.virtualenvs\cta\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 36, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Mr Ayo\.virtualenvs\cta\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1832, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Mr Ayo\.virtualenvs\cta\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1818, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Mr Ayo\Desktop\my_social_trends\views\search.py", line 65, in search
    return render_template("index-home.html")
  File "C:\Users\Mr Ayo\.virtualenvs\cta\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 135, in render_template
    context, ctx.app)
  File "C:\Users\Mr Ayo\.virtualenvs\cta\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 117, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Mr Ayo\.virtualenvs\cta\lib\site-packages\jinja2\asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
    return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mr Ayo\.virtualenvs\cta\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "C:\Users\Mr Ayo\.virtualenvs\cta\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Mr Ayo\.virtualenvs\cta\lib\site-packages\jinja2\_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Mr Ayo\Desktop\my_social_trends\templates\index-home.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends 'main-layout.html' %}
  File "C:\Users\Mr Ayo\Desktop\my_social_trends\templates\main-layout.html", line 142, in top-level template code
    {{ form.name }}
  File "C:\Users\Mr Ayo\.virtualenvs\cta\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 430, in getattr
    return getattr(obj, attribute)
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined
```

Comment: can you please show us your html

Answer (score 0):

The homepage where the signup and login modal is....

```
 {% from "includes/_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
 <!-- Sign Up Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="signUpModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
 labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered sign-modal-dialog" 
  role="document">
            {%include 'includes/_messages.html' %}
            <div class="modal-content sign-modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header sign-modal-header">
                <div class="modal-title sign-modal-title" 
      id="exampleModalCenterTitle">
                   <h5><img src="../static/images/main-images/user-sign.png" alt=""> 
     <span>Create Account</span></h5>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="close sign-close" data-dismiss="modal" 
       aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="get-started">
                    <p>Get Started!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="sign-form">
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        <div class="sign-name">
                            <p><label for="username">Name</label></p>
                            {{ render_field(form.username, class_='signup-form-input 
              form-control' ) }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="sign-email">
                            <p><label for="email">Email Address</label></p>
                          {{ render_field(form.email, class_='signup-form-input form- 
           control' ) }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="sign-password">
                            <p><label for="password">Create Password</label></p>
                           {{ render_field(form.password, class_='signup-form-input 
         form-control' ) }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="sign-password">
                            <p><label for="password">Confirm Password</label></p>
                           {{ render_field(form.password, class_='signup-form-input 
            form-control' ) }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="sign-up-link text-center sign-link">
                              <button type="submit" class= "submit" 
          value="submit">Sign up</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sign-in-link text-center">
                            <p><span><a href=""  data-dismiss="modal" data- 
 toggle="modal" data-target="#signInModalCenter">Sign In</a></span> instead?</p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data- 
    dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div> -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

 <!-- Sign In Modal -->

    <div class="modal fade" id="signInModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
      labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered sign-modal-dialog" 
      role="document">
            <div class="modal-content sign-modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header sign-modal-header">
    <div class="modal-title sign-modal-title" id=" ">
        <h5><img src="../static/images/main-images/user-sign.png" alt=""><span>Welcome 
    Back</span></h5>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="close sign-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria- 
    label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="get-started">
        <p>Sign in to your account.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sign-form">

        <form action="/login" method="post">
            <div class="sign-name">
                <p><label for="username">Username</label></p>
                {{ render_field(form.email, class_='login2-form-input form-control' ) 
     }}
            </div>

            <div class="sign-password ">
                <p><label for="password">Password</label></p>
                {{ render_field(form.password, class_='login2-form-input form-control' 
        ) }}
            </div>


            <div class="sign-up-link text-center">
                 <button type="submit" class="submit" >Login</button>
            </div>
            <div class="sign-in-link text-center">
                <p> Don't have an account?</p>
                <span><a href=""  data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data- 
          target="#signUpModalCenter">Sign Up</a></span>
            </div>
        </form>
     </div>

      </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```